# We are developing the payout using 'Financial Connections' but showing 'No such external account'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

We have a system in mobile app where we are developing  payout (Withdraw amount). We are using stripe.js as a front end development and we are calling rest api for processing server side integration. Steps are given below -

1. Create connect account with  type "Custom"

```
  -u sk_test_51KV********************: \  
  -d country=US \  
  -d type=custom \  
  -d "capabilities[card_payments][requested]"=true \  
  -d "capabilities[transfers][requested]"=true
```

Got an account id - acct_1LUU************

2. Create financial connection session

```
  -u sk_test_51KV7*******************: \
  -d "account_holder[type]"=account \
  -d "account_holder[account]"="acct_1LUU***********" \
  -d "filters[countries][]"=US \
  -d "permissions[]"=ownership \
  -d "permissions[]"=payment_method
```

Got client secret - fcsess_client_secret_ECVx*******************

3. Initialize stripe.js with the client secret and after bank connect we got bank token - btok_1LUU******************

```
this.stripe.collectBankAccountToken({
      clientSecret: 'fcsess_client_secret_ECVx**********************'
    })
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
        if (result.error) {
          // Inform the customer that there was an error.
          console.log(result.error.message);
        } else if (result.token) {
          // Use result.token to set your user's external payout account
          console.log(result.token)
        }
      });
```

4. Create external account for payout

```
  -u sk_test_51KV********************************************************: \
  -d external_account="btok_1LUU********************"
```

Got external account bank details - ba_1LUU************************

5. Process the external account for payout

```
  -u sk_test_51KV*************************************************: \
  -d amount=1100 \
  -d currency=usd
  -d destination=ba_1LUU*******************************
```

Got an error -

```
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such external account: 'ba_1LUU*********************'",
    "param": "destination",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

We are not able to process payout. What should we do?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Stripe customer support?

Comment: These resource_missing errors usually occur when you use the wrong API key (ie. object was created on platform account but you use stripe-account header and try to reference the object on your connect account or vice-versa).